# DateTimePicker control displays date incorrectly after Windows 10 update

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

After I updated to Windows 10 Build 15063, my DateTimePicker control displays incorrectly. It appears to have tabs it the display output. When I pick a date the value is set correctly in the control but will display like this

`02/                       /02                        /2016`

[image]

When I set a text box to the text value of the DateTimePicker is set correctly. 
Does anyone have any ideas on this? I have attached a print screen of the output.

When I run the code in Windows 10 Build 14393 it comes out correctly

Example 01

`dtpDate.Text` returns "02/02/2016"

Example 02

```
Me.dtpDate.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
Me.dtpDate.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
Me.dtpDate.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(80, 80)
Me.dtpDate.Name = "dtpDate"
Me.dtpDate.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(88, 20)
Me.dtpDate.TabIndex = 6
```

Comment: Similar issue posted a week ago on MSDN https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6174aa28-29cc-4749-bc02-5c02a1b3ff85/datepicker-issue-in-windows-10?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: I found this one also   https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/45389/datetimepicker-control-broken-after-upgrade-to-win.html

Comment: So the short-term fix is putting `System.Windows.Forms.Application.EnableVisualStyles()` in Form.Load. Then wait for M$ to fix it.

Comment: The short term fix worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is resolved by KB4022725 (June cumulative update)

Answer (score 0):

For visual studio 2010,  Go through Project --> properties, under the application tab, activate "Enable XP visual styles"

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem with my MFC application. The CDateTimeCtrl worked fine in dialogs until a Windows Update broke it (making show either "//" or dates with truncated digits).

The bug appears to be in COMCTL32.dll version 5. I was able to work around it by forcing my app to use COMCTL32.dll version 6, by inserting the following into my code:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \ 
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \ 
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

This altered the appearance of some other things, but it worked.

I read that this problem with version 5 may go away with June cumulative update for Windows 10.